# 404 when trying to serve Markdown (.md) files locally

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, markdown

### I'm trying to read text from a file saved in my website's directory but keep getting a 404 error when attempting to find it.

The directory structure is simple in this example:

```
+ - index.html
|
+ - README.md
|
+ - license.txt
|
+ - js
     |
     + - app.js
```

Inside of `app.js` I have the following function that allows one to look for files and read their text.

```
    function findPostContent(file) {
        var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var allText = {};
        rawFile.open("GET", file, false);

        rawFile.send();

        if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status === 0) {
            allText = rawFile.responseText;
            return;
        }

        console.log("can't find file");

        return allText;
    }
```

---

When I run it looking for `license.txt` it finds it without fail. However when I run it looking for `README.md` I get a 404.

```
findPostContent("license.txt"); // Works fine!
findPostContent("README.md");   // 404?
```

Anyone have any insights as to why this is occurring? I thought this might be a [security issue, per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript) but if so, why is it able to read `license.txt` without fail?

Comment: Make sure that your README.md is not decapitalized when you deploy the file. requests are case-sensitive.

Comment: thanks @VladimirM - the casing is the same in both cases. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you manage to solve the error? I'm in the same situation...

Comment: unfortunately no, if i remember correctly, I ended up just creating the markdown on the server instead. Sorry, wish i had a better answer